# How to specify local registry in yarn?

Tags: node.js, nexus, yarnpkg

I have a local nexus server, I'd like yarn to look through it before going online, basically `prefer-offline`

```sh
yarn install \
  --prefer-offline \
  --cache-folder C:\folder\yarn-cache \
  --preferred-cache-folder C:\folder\yarn-cache \
  --non-interactive \
  --no-lockfile \
  --registry http://server/repository/npm-group
```

Yarn fails to find a dependency offline then fails to go online. I don't know if that can be fixed.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

- Create an *npm (hosted)* repository to use as your private registry.
  I believe you have already done this.
- Create an *npm (proxy)*
  repository pointing to your external repository of choice
  (https://registry.yarnpkg.com or https://registry.npmjs.org/).
- Create an *npm (group)* with your private registry on first position and the proxy registry on second position.
- Point *yarn* to your group repository: `yarn config set registry http://nexus.local/repository/npm-group/`. If required by your Nexus configuration, authenticate yarn: `yarn login`.

Also be wary of *yarn* using any *npm* config you might have over it's own: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4862

**Update for Yarn v2+:**

Yarn v2+ uses a different configuration key for updating the NPM registry, called npmRegistryServer (see their [Migration](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#update-your-configuration-to-the-new-settings) page for details):

```
yarn config set npmRegistryServer http://nexus.local/repository/npm-group/
```

Comment: What about the authToken?

Answer (score 37):

You can set a different registry in yarn by using the following command:

```
yarn config set registry <url-to-your-registry>
```

Verify that it has been set by typing the following command:

```
yarn config get registry
```

For a one-off change in registry you can use the variable `YARN_REGISTRY` like this:

```
YARN_REGISTRY="<url-to-your-registry>" yarn config get registry
```

or

```
YARN_REGISTRY="<url-to-your-registry>" yarn publish
```

Comment: Thanks. This was a head scratcher since the docs say `--registry` on the cli for a one-off.

Comment: Welcome, I faced the same issue when I was trying it. Felt like this should be posted as an answer here.

Comment: For the _NPM_ registry in Yarn v4.0.2, this is what I used: `YARN_NPM_REGISTRY_SERVER=https://registry.npmjs.org yarn config get npmRegistryServer`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `.yarnrc` file & add `registry "<your repo URL>"`
Refer - [yarnrc](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarnrc/)

Comment: the file itself says "do not edit this file directly" - `yarn config set registry` is preferred

Answer (score 4):

Also don't forget to regenerate yarn.lock file after changing registry. It's neccessary because yarn.lock contains links to old registry and will try to install dependencies from that links.

Answer (score 3):

**Heads up!**

If you define your `publishConfig.registry` in `package.json`:

```
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org"
  },
```

It will **still override** registry, even if `--registry` param was given to `yarn publish`!

Answer (score 3):

### Hey Yarn 1 users

1. If you want to **config a registry for a specific repo**, it should go to the `.npmrc` file in your repo. `.yarnrc` is supposed to [configure additional Yarn features](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarnrc#:%7E:text=configure%20additional%20Yarn%20features)
2. However It's **OK** if you put it in `.yarnrc` file. Yarn will read both `.npmrc` and `.yarnrc` file.
3. If you want to **config registry globally**, run the following command(eg: I am using `https://registry.npmmirror.com` registry):

   ```bash
   yarn config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com
   ```

   Note this add registry to the `.yarnrc` your user home directory (`~/.yarnrc`). The added line is like this:

   ```
   registry "https://registry.npmmirror.com"
   ```

For **Yarn 2** users, [try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49976891/2710165).

### For NPM users

1. Config registry for a repo:

   ```bash
   npm config --location=project set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com
   ```
2. Config registry globally(`~/.npmrc`):

   ```bash
   npm config --location=global set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com
   ```

Comment: `--location=local` is not a valid option for location, it's one of these three: `global`, `user`, `project`.

Comment: @Sgnl Thanks. I double checked and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `yarn 3 a.k.a. Berry`:

```bash
yarn config set 'npmRegistries["http://npm.example.com"]'
```