# Installing private Github Package using yarn on Github Actions is Unauthorized with yarn.lock

Tags: yarnpkg, github-actions, github-package-registry

There are a lot of similar issues already floating around:

- [Install private github package from package.json on Github Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53614077/install-private-github-package-from-package-json-on-github-actions)
- [Download private module from Github Package Registry via Yarn within a Github Action? Publishing works, but installing is met with '401 Unauthorized'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975181/download-private-module-from-github-package-registry-via-yarn-within-a-github-ac)
- [Installing private package from Github Package registry using Yarn fails with not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61738819/installing-private-package-from-github-package-registry-using-yarn-fails-with-no)

However, our issue seems different, because:

- `yarn install` runs fine on a local machine
- the issue is only when using Github Actions
- `yarn install` **succeeds** on GH Actions if we delete `yarn.lock`

Has anyone run into this before? Specifically with it not working with a `yarn.lock` file?

In case it matters, here's the setup:

`build.yml`:

```
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '10.x'
        registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
    - name: Install
      run: yarn install
      env:
        # GITHUB_TOKEN can't access packages hosted in private repos,
        # even within the same organisation
        NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
    - name: Build
      run: yarn build
    - name: Test
      run: yarn test --forbid-only
```

We also have a `.npmrc` file for local installs:

```
@<org>:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

But **no** `.yarnrc` file.

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: I have never had to run `yarn install`. When I [use yarn](https://github.com/Actions-R-Us/actions-tagger/blob/1cbce767f3858f11d48a7ba9fffc9c8cd45a83e1/.github/workflows/test.yml) on github actions, I run `yarn --frozen-lockfile` to do the install and force yarn to use the `yarn.lock` without checking for updates or anything. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58480279/2089675) also

Comment: We're just told that the request is unauthorized:

`yarn install v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/<scope>/<package>/<version>/<hash>: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to solve this by explicitly duplicating the `.npmrc` config in the `build.yml` config:

```yml
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '10.x'
          registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
          # These following two lines are the key:
          always-auth: true
          scope: '@reedsy'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm create a file .npmrc and .yarnrc.
Type:

```
name: Test

on: push
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Node ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Create NPMRC
        run: |
            echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.PACKAGES_TOKEN }}" >> ~/.npmrc
            echo "@you-scope:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com" >> ~/.npmrc
            echo 'registry "https://registry.yarnpkg.com"' >> ~/.yarnrc
      - run: yarn install
```

Replace @you-scope for you user of github or of your org in github in **LowerCase**.

Create a PACKAGES_TOKEN secrete token of your github access for this repository.

Comment: Your note about requiring a PACKAGES_TOKEN proved helpful.  I kept trying the GITHUB_TOKEN in the actions but that was leading to a 404 Not Found.  I'm guessing the GITHUB_TOKEN in actions is only valid for the current repository and not for installing other packages, even if in the same organization.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. I was missing the step of creating NPMRC